# To check the serialize array

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have to fetch the wp-options table from the wordpress database and i have to unserialise the serialise data. my code for get the option values from the database table is written bellow.

```
function option_value_change () {
  global $wpdb;
  $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT *
  FROM `wp_options`");
    foreach ($myrows as $rows){
      $option = get_option($rows->option_name);
      modify_domain_name($option);
            echo $rows-> option_value ."<br />";
    }
}
```

Now i want to check the serialise data. How can i check the data as serialise data.If that is a serialise data then how can i unserialise that data.

Comment: you may use unserialize(). check http://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/unserialize.php

Comment: you can use php function unserialize() and serialize() for this

Comment: I want to check the data(which i got as output) is serialise or simple data in php script. like if(serialise($rows-> option_value)) or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe check if it is an object, or an array, and if not, then unserialize it.

```
<?php
if (!is_array($var) && !is_object($var)) {
  $var = unserialize($var);
}
?>
```

Or, depending on if your data is positively going to either be an object/array, or serialized data, you could also just test if it is a string.

```
<?php
if (is_string($var)) {
  $var = unserialize($var);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a function called [maybe_unserialize()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) that will fit your job.

As its name suggest, the function will unserialize a variable only if it is serialized.

**EDIT:**

I don't know your current needs, but just in case you didn't know, WordPress has a [get_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) function which reads a value form the `options` table and unserialize it if needed before returning it to you.